# Decimal Value addition not working, returning string

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating-point, decimal

I want to do some math like plus, minus etc. with decimal values.

So i wrote two functions;

```
function to_decimal(i){
    var $dec = parseFloat(i);
    return $dec.toFixed(2);
}

function calc_price(){
    var $t = $('#sub_total .total').text();
    var $total = to_decimal($t);

    $('#price_list ul li').each(function(){
        var $p = to_decimal($(this).find('.item_price').text());
        $total = $total + $p;
    });

    $t = $('#sub_total .total').text($total);
}
```

But these functions not working correctly i think because the result is returning string like 0.0010.30

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a `+` infront of that statement and you're fine:

```
return +$dec.toFixed(2);
```

That will convert the string into a number. If the string cannot get converted, it'll return the `NaN` value.

Comment: As an equivalent alternative, I often use `$dec.toFixed(2) * 1` instead (multiplication by one). I feel like I'm more likely to notice my intent later; the `+` can be hard to miss.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
return $dec.toFixed(2);
```

Do:

```
return Math.round($dec*100)/100;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `toFixed` method returns a string. Any mathematical operation that doesn't affect the output can be used to convert the string to a number (except addition, whose operator unfortunately doubles as the string concatenation operator):

```
$dec.toFixed(2) - 0 
$dec.toFixed(2) / 1 
$dec.toFixed(2) * 1
+$dec.toFixed(2)
```

These are the fastest methods. However, if speed is not a concern (and it probably isn't when performing a small number of operations) then the clearest, most-readable method to convert a string to a number is the `Number` constructor:

```
Number($dec.toFixed(2))
```

**Edit:** The performance information above may no longer be universally true. The `Number` constructor is indeed considerably slower than each of the alternatives in IE 7.0 and Firefox 5, but actually performs the best in Chrome 12.0.742.

See:

- http://jsperf.com/js-string-to-number-conversion

Comment: Thank you. I learned something from your post. But jAndy's response is worked fine.